# how to show the dynamic logs of one jsp page in another frame using ajax/jsp

Tags: java, html, ajax, multithreading, jsp

I am new to ajax and jsp. This is about a multithreading kind of problem that I faced.

I am using ajax to embed a jsp page in one frame of my web-page, in which a client server udp transfer is going on. I need some log messages during this udp transfer to be displayed as status info in the main page.

The problem is that while the udp transfer is busy, I am not able to update the web page with normal code dynamically [using out.println in jsp]. But am able to see the output stream log dynamically(created using System.out.println), in netbeans debugger.

(I have tried to create a new thread in jsp, but couldnt use the JSPWriter->out inside the thread, also not sure if this was a good idea)

Any clues on a way to show the logs dynamically in the main page would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to display a status message, then you can work around with CSS and java script to show some message and update the final log.

But if you need exact staus message to be updated in the frame, then you need to go for reverse ajax, or pushlets. Please refer DWR ajax framework.

Thanks